# Firebase cloud function dart kill all functions

Tags: dart, google-cloud-platform

I am searching for preventing attacks like Ddos, I am not sure I came across a solution.

**Case 1**

in which from every request putting a increment value in firestore database. After certain value such as 100000 a cloud function will trigger which will destroy / deactivate all my cloud functions.

**Case 2**

Is there any easy way using if else in cloud functions.

I am new to Firebase cloud functions
I am writing cloud functions in dart

Is there any way to write security rules for calling function

Is there any way to limit invocations

Can cdn or another service integration help in this situation. I dnt want surprise bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, see this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/security-checklist) on the guidelines you should follow to avoid security attacks in Firebase.

> 1. in which from every request putting a increment value in firestore database. After certain value such as 100000 a cloud function will trigger which will destroy / deactivate all my cloud functions.

Unfortunately, this is not how a managed service works. Cloud Functions can only be triggered when invoked or during a response to an event. If there's no traffic, then the function is not running. It's not possible to deactivate them.

You can however, list all you functions and delete them one-by-one by using Cloud Functions Client Library and method [deleteFunction()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/nodejs-functions/latest/v1.CloudFunctionsServiceClient.html#deleteFunction).

> 2. Is there any easy way using if else in cloud functions.

For this question, are you referring to conditional statements or on how a traffic is redirected?

> 3. I am new to Firebase cloud functions I am writing cloud functions in dart

Currently, there is no official way to deploy a function running in Dart Runtime, though there are [community supported projects](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dart) that allow you to run Dart functions on other environments.

Node is the only runtime being supported in Cloud Function for Firebase as of the moment. See documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options).

> 4. Is there any way to write security rules for calling function

Firebase security rules are for Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601453/7031308) that shows how to protect HTTP functions using auth id tokens and database rules.

Additionally, in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started), you can find how to setup security rules in your Firebase project. Sample scripts can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics).

> 5. Is there any way to limit invocations

You can find a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741936/rate-limiting-for-google-firebase-cloud-functions) on limiting invocations in Firebase Cloud Functions. Additional details regarding Quotas and Limits can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas).

> 6. Can cdn or another service integration help in this situation. I dnt want surprise bill

CDNs can help you bring down costs due to caching behavior, however it is not the complete solution to avoid surprise bills. One way to avoid this is to setup budget alerts to send email notifications whenever your project exceeds (or about to exceed) the set spend threshold. See documentation on Avoiding surprise bills [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/avoid-surprise-bills?hl=ro).

Comment: Does doing this will not cost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741936/rate-limiting-for-google-firebase-cloud-functions. And I mean detaching user from functions completely. And is there any way to write security rules before anyone can call my function. Just how we do this for firestore security rules

Comment: can u please look at this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847507/firebase-cloud-functions-upper-limit-and-time-limit

Comment: As per checking, your new posted question has already been answered. 
For this question, "And is there any way to write security rules before anyone can call my function. Just how we do this for firestore security rules", you can create a new question for this so the community can contribute. Additionally, you can check this link https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating on how to authenticate invocations.