# firebase cloud functions upper limit and time limit

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

I tried firebase blaze plan calculator. I wanted to check the upper limit of cloud functions.
[image]

Total turned out is 176$
Incase of Ddos or any other attack will it only cost this much and I also found a article saying 5000 invocations per second. Can it cost more than this
Edit : Can I set hard limit on cloud functions to prevent ddos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper limit you specify is part of the calculator, and not part of Cloud Functions itself. Cloud Functions itself scales with the number of incoming requests, up to the [maximum number of concurrent requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances) that you specify.

Comment: so, if I set max-instances 100, only 100 invocations or requests will be made & can I edit 
max instances later

Comment: It's the maximum number of **concurrent** requests, not the maximum number of total requests.

Comment: Is there any way to set maximum number of request either with another cloud function?

Comment: I think you should check out some of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=set+hard+limit+on+cloud+functions+to+prevent+ddos, https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+maximum+request+quota+for+cloud+functions and https://www.google.com/search?q=set+a+maximum+for+firebase+bill, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks and this video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWrZwXK92IM&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmK1tiMBeKA0iDMPDCJKM-5. I merely answered your mistaken assumption about the maximum charge that the calculator shows.